# Is it possible to tell if a site is using anonymizeIp in ga.js script?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, privacy

I used Ghostery to find out what sites are sending info to Google Analytics using the `ga.js` script.

I'm browsing in Firefox, and I wondered if there's a way of telling if they are turning on the `anonymizeIp` function or not.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the network tab for a call to the Google server that starts with `"collect/"...` (this will be the call to *Google Analytics*).

See if it includes a parameter called `&aip` which stands for (rather obviously) "anonymize ip".

If anonymized it will usually be set to `1`, but AFAIK any value will enable anonymization.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this code in your browser console to get the settings of all trackers on the page:

```
ga(function() {
  var trackers = ga.getAll();
  for (i = 0; i < trackers.length; i++) { 
    var values = trackers[i].b.data.values;
    console.log(values[":trackingId"],values[":anonymizeIp"]);
  }
});
```

By default the `anonymizeIp` property isn't set, so you will see `undefined`, on Stackoverflow we see:

```
UA-108242619-1 undefined
```

If you set it:

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

And run the command again, you'll see set to `true`.